# Wafer lights with CRI 93

Tags: recessed-lighting

I looked in a few places for wafer-style recessed LED downlights with a CRI higher than 90 (preferably 93-95) at 5000k, but haven't been able to find anything. Has anyone done this before?

I saw LED strips at CRI 95 and the much larger canned-style recessed lights at CRI 94, but I think if I went that route I'd just install recessed E26 sockets and put in my own high CRI bulbs.

I don't know anything about sourcing this kind of stuff. Should I just ask an electrician to help me or do they tend to just work with what they have in stock?

Edit: I don't want product recommendations. Just to know if anyone has seen wafer-style lights with high CRI.

Comment: I have sources for high CRI E27, GU10 and strips, but haven't found the high CRI wafer lights yet. So I'm following the question ;)

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see answers like that @bob.  Product reco's are specifically off-topic on StackExchange system-wide.

Comment: I don't even need a product recommendation. It would be helpful to know if what I am searching for exists, so I can know whether it makes any sense to continue searching.

Answer (score 2):

Buy lighting at a *lighting supply house* not an electrician.

You will recognize them because they have *hundreds and hundreds* of lights on display in a showroom.  Generally speaking, lighting is all they do.

Electricians are not retail shops and do not "stock" anything.  They might have product catalogs on their truck, but they would refer you to a lighting supply store they like, and say "call me once you've ordered".

Comment: Alternatively, some big-box stores _do_ have a fairly substantial supply of lights, ranging into the 100s of different devices, it _may_ be possible to find what the OP is looking for there. Of course, I do support shopping at a locally owned lighting supply house...